# app crashes on UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I present a UIActivityView controller, my app crashes with

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

But if I specify the popoverPresentationController, the app doesn't crash. However it doesn't show the animation where it slides in from the bottom. Instead, it just pops up in the top left.

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: [])
vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Any ideas on what I can do to make sure it still retains the default animation of sliding in from the bottom?

Comment: Check that you are presenting this on main thread

Comment: doesn't work :/

Comment: try removing `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover` in my code works without that

Comment: That and the line below it allow the app to work. If I take those out, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Hello World"], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
})
```

Comment: You are using iPhone or iPad ?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone

Comment: does it give the same error? Could you paste the stack trace ?

Comment: yes gives the same error. Here's the stack trace: http://imgur.com/a/rAE3s

Comment: stack trace doesn't help... anything special about the crash logs you get ? like something nil apart from libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException also, which iOS version are you on ?

Comment: nothing special. This happens only when the user first installs the app. Every other time, this works fine. I'm guessing it's because when they first install the app and sign up, I'm presenting the sign up page with `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`. Every other time it just goes to the initial vc. Perhaps I'm presenting the view controller wrong in the app delegate?

Comment: actually why don't you present your sign up page (modally) at initial launch on basis of whether user details are present on not ?
This could be done in your initial view controller itself, probably in view will appear.